# Proper way to find an Account via one of its associated RefreshTokens in Sequelize with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am writing my first project using TypeScript + Sequelize and I'm having some difficulties setting it up.

My goal is to make the Account model have many RefreshTokens in a one to many relationship, and then be able to access the RefreshTokens associated with a given account. Or find the Account associated with a given RefreshToken.

I suspect there is no answer under 40 lines or so. There's a lot of boilerplate!

In `initModels.ts`:

```
const Account = _Account.initModel(sequelize);
const RefreshToken = _RefreshToken.initModel(sequelize);
Account.hasMany(RefreshToken);
RefreshToken.belongsTo(Account);
```

This is the command I'm really trying to make work for me:

```
export const getAccountByRefreshToken = (token: RefreshToken) => {
     // this line is obviously wrong but the func name will explain what I'm aiming at
    return Account.findOne({ where: { refreshToken: token } });
};
```

I'm going to post an abridged version of my Account and RefreshToken models. Because otherwise this post would be enormous.

`RefreshToken.ts`:

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize, Model, Optional } from "sequelize";

import sequelizeConnection from "../Database";

interface RefreshTokenAttributes {
    accountId: number; // todo: link to User model
    token: string;
}

export type RefreshTokenOptionalAttributes = "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "deletedAt";
export type RefreshTokenCreationAttributes = Optional<RefreshTokenAttributes, RefreshTokenOptionalAttributes>;

export class RefreshToken extends Model<RefreshTokenAttributes, RefreshTokenCreationAttributes> implements RefreshTokenAttributes {
    public accountId!: number;
    public token!: string;


    static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize): typeof RefreshToken {
        return RefreshToken.init(
            {
                accountId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, // todo: link to user model.
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                token: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },
        );
    }
}
```

`Account.ts`:

```
import { DataTypes, Sequelize, Model, Optional } from "sequelize";

import sequelizeConnection from "../Database";

interface AccountAttributes {
    id: number;
    email: string;
}

export type AccountOptionalAttributes = "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "deletedAt";
export type AccountCreationAttributes = Optional<AccountAttributes, AccountOptionalAttributes>;

export class Account extends Model<AccountAttributes, AccountCreationAttributes> implements AccountAttributes {
    public id!: number;
    public email!: string;

    static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize): typeof Account {
        return Account.init(
            {
                id: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                email: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },

        );
    }
}
```

I don't really *get* what precisely it is about a program that lets the Sequelize library know "oh hey I want to associate these two tables." It looks to me like the combo of TS + Sequelize is something people started doing in the past 2-3 years, because there really isn't a lot of info about how to implement this. I've been stalled on this for months so, if someone could even drop a link to an article, I'd appreciate it. "You can see this article describing how to do it when it says *such and such*" would be helpful. I'm not so sure I'll recognize all the steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

If `refreshToken` passed in

```js
Account.findOne({ where: { refreshToken: token } });
```

has `id` then you need to use it in `where` condition in the associated `RefreshToken` model like this:

```js
Account.findOne({
  include: [{
    // this option is important, otherwise you will get all accounts 
    // and only in one of them you will get the single token where its id is equal to token.id
    required: true,
    model: RefreshToken,
    where: { id: token.id }
  }]
});
```